# Finding hardware-specific git repos

Tags: drivers, hardware, git

Is there a way for me to know the hardware-specific git repositories for drivers and where I could find them?

Some examples of ones that I've already found are:

[Android Device ASUS Z008](http://github.com/cyanogenmod/android_device_asus_Z008)

[Proprietary Vendor ASUS](https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_asus)

My vendor is ASUS.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to search for `git` repositories from your local system like with `apt` or `docker`, simply because there is no centralized servers for this type of software. `git` isn't really for software "download" or package distribution, but for source code version control.

You still can search Github and Gitlab sites, but that's as far as it gets.  And of course you have to rely on the internet search engine of your choice.